# EXCH provider referencing wrong FQDN in Autodiscover.xml in Exchange 2010?

Tags: ssl-certificate, exchange-2010, autodiscover

Our public-facing domain name changed last year, but active directory still uses the old domain name. This didn't pose a problem until we updated the SSL certificate in Exchange 2010. Now, even after changing `AutoDiscoverServiceInternalUri` on the Client Access Server, and remapping all Virtual Directories, Outlook clients are still displaying a single stubborn certificate warning.

When running the ***Test Email AutoConfiguration Tool*** from the Outlook client, I noted that the `EXCH` provider is referencing ***hostname*.old-domain.com**, while the `EXPR` provider is correctly mapped to **mail.new-domain.com**, as `EXCH` should be.

```
<Protocol>
    <Type>EXCH</Type>
    <Server>EXCH-1.old-domain.com</Server>
    ...
</Protocol>
<Protocol>
    <Type>EXPR</Type>
    <Server>mail.new-domain.com</Server>
    ...
</Protocol>
```

Is it possible to update this section of Autodiscover without changing the AD domain suffix?

Update: It seems that the error is only appearing for internally connected clients on LAN.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Run the following command in EMS, then restart the IIS service on all CAS servers by running *iisreset*(You may schedule a down time to restart this server, as it would temporarily affect the Exchange services replying on it):

***Set-OutlookProvider -Identity EXCH -CertPrincipalName msstd:mail.new-domain.com***

Actually, you can also set the *CertPrincipleName* of EXCH as null. Thus it will not force the Outlook client to connect to the specified server name. The proper domain name will be auto-populated.

Below are the Microsoft blogs for your reference:

[The Autodiscover Service and Outlook Providers – how does this stuff work?](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2008/09/26/the-autodiscover-service-and-outlook-providers-how-does-this-stuff-work/)

[When, if and how do you modify Outlook Providers?](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2008/09/29/when-if-and-how-do-you-modify-outlook-providers/)